# In JOSM, adjusting one line to follow another

Tags: openstreetmap, josm

I would like to adjust a rudimentary drawn area (neighborhood) so that it uses the same nodes as the nearby streets. Doing it by hand seems very combersome - I use "a" or a nearby plus symbol to create a new node on the way, then I select it, and shift+select nearby street node, and hit "m" (merge).  How do I select "bad" line, and make it auto-join all the nearby nodes along the way, possibly with clicks or a keystroke.  I know about "follow", but that only works for a new drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JOSM has a [follow mode](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Help/Action/FollowLine). Draw your way by using two consecutive nodes of an existing way, then just repeatedly press f to follow this way.

However most OSM editors are against joining highways with areas. Therefore I suggest to draw the neighborhood area completely separate instead of re-using nodes from the street.

Comment: thx, but what about **existing** ways - if I have two ways right next to each other (two neighborhoods next to each with a mutual border), I would like to reuse that way segment, instead of having two separate sets of nodes. Is there a way to select one way and interactively glue it with another?

Comment: My personal workflow is to split one of the areas at the shared border, delete this way and re-draw it along the existing way of the other border using follow mode. JOSM has various advanced tools in various addons, maybe there is an alternative approach.

Answer (score -1):

[Contourmerge](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Help/Plugin/ContourMerge) plugin.

Beware is it very powerful.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Please, can you provide more information about it? Links could become invalid, so any additional explanation would be welcomed.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please don't just offer a link to a potential solution - instead **[edit]** your answer to give some detail on how to use it, and how it answers the question.  Link only answers without additional information may be deleted.